# How to refresh google maps UI now that resize is gone?

Tags: google-maps

I add jqueryUI elements into my map controls for google maps, when an accordion expands, it will collide with another UI element.
I used to use the resize event to redraw google maps UI to make the spacing fix itself, now they removed that in 3.32+.

I am currently using `map.setCenter(map.getCenter());` but there are instances where some race condition happens and it will center my map on the USA while its trying to zoom into another state. Not only that but getting the center and setting the center seems to be quite slow. I use to trigger a `resize` every 50 ms in order for the animations to be smooth on the UI, I can't do that with center because it happens like once every 250 ms

I tried `map.setZoom(map.getZoom());` and it's less prone to race conditions and is very speedy but setting the zoom to the exact same zoom triggers a getTile call and makes my overlayview flicker

Comment: Can you post your code with problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can still listen to window `resize` event and trigger event with same name on the map.

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
  zoom: 14,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// listen for the window resize event & trigger Google Maps to update too
window.onresize = function() {
  var currCenter = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.setCenter(currCenter);
};
```

```html
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
```